# Update a table's column from another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I've got two tables. One is `payment1` and the other is `payment2`. They both have 4 mutual columns. `Id, InvoiceNumber, TransactionCode` and `Date`. In table `payment1`, some of the `TransactionCode` are different or missing. Since just some of them are different, I want to update it using `TransactionCode` from `payment2` according to the `Id` number where they are different.

I know it's a bit confusing so let me explain it using an example:

- in table payment1, Id is 926 and the Transaction code is 5398. In table payment2, Id is 926 but the transaction code is 53269845.
- in table payment1, Id is 927 and the Transaction code is null. In table payment2, Id is 926 but the transaction code is 54895321.

I want to say where `Id`s are the same, update the `TransactionCode` using another table.

I tried this:

```
"update payment1 set payment1.TransactionCode=payment2.TransactionCode
from payment1 
join payment2 on (payment1.TransactionCode=payment2.TransactionCode)"
```

and this was the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 from payment join table63 on (payment1.TransactionCode=payment2.TransactionCode)' at line 1
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Sample data and a correct database tag would be a big help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MySQL on phpMyAdmin

Comment: So, Payment 2 Table is having correct Data ?

Comment: show us what you tried. you might need to use `update..join` statement. google it. try it. if it doesnt work, post the error here.

Comment: only those values will get inserted from payment2 table which are not equal to payment1 table.. or you want to copy all data from payment2 to payment1 by matching ID

Comment: Only the ones which do not match. @DanishEnam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Payment1 P1 
SET P1.TransactionCode= (SELECT P2.TansactionCode FROM Payment2 P2 WHERE P1.TransactionCode<>P2.TransactionCode AND P1.Id=P2.Id)
```

OR

```
UPDATE Payment1
SET Payment1.TransactionCode= (SELECT Payment2.TansactionCode FROM Payment2 WHERE Payment1.TransactionCode<>Payment2.TransactionCode AND Payment1.Id=Payment2.Id)
```

Where, Payment1 & Payment2 are table name (assumed)
And, ID & TransactionCode Are column Name (assumed)

Comment: I don't get it, what is P2 and P1?

Comment: It's alias name @Sean. 
You can write like this way also.. 

UPDATE Payment1
SET Payment1.TransactionCode= (SELECT Payment2.TansactionCode FROM Payment2 WHERE Payment1.TransactionCode<>Payment2.TransactionCode AND Payment1.Id=Payment2.Id)

Comment: I will check and respond you ASAP. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: SELECT payment1.TransactionCode , payment2.TransactionCode
      FROM payment1
       LEFT JOIN payment2
        ON payment1.Id = payment2.Id
I managed to select the two arrows for the sake of comparison. However, now I want to replace them. As in payment2.TransactionCode into payment1.TransactionCode. I gotta use update, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

```
    update payment1 TB1
    set TB1.Transactioncode=(select B.Transactioncode from payment2 B
    JOIN payment1 a
    on a.Transactioncode=B.Transactioncode AND B.Transactioncode=TB1.Transactioncode)
```